# to get latitude and longitude by passing address

Tags: java-me

i want to get the latitude and longitude by passing the address in url.
i want to get the responce in xml format.
i had try to google it out i got this 
1)http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html

But this is geving the responce of 
REQUEST_DENIED

And then 
2)http://www.storm-consultancy.com/blog/development/code-snippets/using-google-maps-api-to-get-latitude-longitude-co-ordinates-from-postcode-or-address/

In this i must have api_key of google.

Now i dont have the api_key.

Is there any another way to get latitude and longitude by pasing address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to use the Google API then you can [get an API key](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html).

There are [other resources](https://webgis.usc.edu/Services/Geocode/Default.aspx) you can try as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should google for **geocoding**. Maybe you find something on [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Geocoding)